# Not able to supply params to Facebook post dialog

Tags: android, facebook

I am using following code to pre-populate the post dialog. But I'm getting a empty dialogbox, nevertheless:

```
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("app_id", appID);
        parameters.putString("name", "Facebook Dialog");
        parameters.putString("caption", "Reference Documentation");

        parameters.putString("message", "Facebook Dialogs are easy!");

        facebook.dialog(score.this, "feed", parameters, new DialogListener() {

            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(DialogError e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
            }
        });
```

However, if it is possible, I would like no dialog at all and directly post to the users wall.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't develop for Android, but I know Facebook made a change in handling of the `message` parameter in the feed dialog that might be causing your problem.

It has always been against policy to pre-populate the `message` parameter.  It must be user-generated.  At some point in the last couple of months Facebook stopped even accepting it for use in the Feed dialog, which is what might be causing your problem.  Now the only way you can pass it as a parameter is by posting to the feed via the graph API.  Of course you still need to be sure to comply with policy in your app design and make the user populate the message -- it cannot be an app-generated string.

So, since you don't even want the dialog, you should really look into posting via the graph API.  You will need to obtain the publish_stream extended permission and then perform a POST to the user's feed.  See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/